# Fetch API with multiple possible servers

Tags: javascript, fetch

I am wondering what the standard way is to allow for JS to fetch from multiple possible locations. In my case I am trying to populate a table on my web app through JS fetch, but there are two possible servers that could be online or offline depending on the situation (I have a localhost server and a server found online). I only want to fetch from one if both are online (or at the very least only populate the table with data from one of them).

I have read a bit into the Promise.all function, but I have been hitting errors with that and can't find much documentation to help me out on it (I presume that the problem could perhaps arise if one of the fetches fails while the others succeed). I have also tried looking into some rather in-depth methods (up to twenty lines long worth of code) to see if a server is actually online or not, but this does seem to get quite messy quite fast.

I have also tried just fetching from both on all occasions, but for some reason this fills my table with undefined values on top of the one's I expect (debugging of this seems to reveal that some of the fetches return objects and some return arrays for a reason I can't figure out, maybe because of the async nature).

Is there a method I should be using or researching further for this? Does this trouble come up in real-world applications, or are developers always sure to make sure that all data comes from the one server? Should I only be fetching data from one server and therefore stop running my localhost one? Thank you for all help.

Comment: I would consider creating a health check endpoint on each server, `/health` that just returns a 200 and maybe a { status: "healthy" }. You'd ping each server to see if it's online and then make the request. Alternatively, you could set up the fetch from the one that's first priority and if it doesn't return successfully, you could call the second one in the error handling.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. It didn't end up quite helping me out as I still had this trouble with a bunch of undefined's popping up even when I tried to check for a healthy server first or by putting the code in the catch(err) part of the bloc. The below answer for Promise.race() seems to have provided me with what I needed (though I am not sure I yet understand why I had all the undefined's in the first place).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, it would be good to point out that you probably don't want to do this for a production app.  I am simply responding to the question of using one of multiple possible values from different fetches, specifically the one that resolved first.

As you may know [Promise.all()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all) is only going to resolve when all the fetches resolve and it's going to resolve with an array containing the resolved value from each fetch.  If any of the fetches reject, Promise.all() rejects also.

An easier route would be to use [Promise.race()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/race) which resolves with value of the first input Promise to resolve.  An example would be:

```
const promise1 = fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1')
  .then(response => response.json())

const promise2 = fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/2')
  .then(response => response.json())

Promise.race([promise1, promise2]).then((value) => {
  console.log(value)
});
```

Comment: Thank you for this answer. It seems to exactly be what I am looking for. This means that Promise.race() can never resolve with more than one fetch right?

Comment: Is there any instance where having multiple possible servers is considered a good practise? For example a user might be accessing the web application in offline mode accessing a copy of the server on their own computer (hence the localhost part)?

Comment: Correct, Promise.race() can never resolve with more than one fetch.  About best practices, maybe someone can answer better than I, but this is my opinion.  1) Your local server is going to end up beating the remote server every time, so you've essentially short-circuited it. 2) It's overly chatty, your now sending 2 requests every time guaranteed. 3) What if there is a data mismatch between the servers?  Wouldn't it be better to know which one you are associating with?